# Get innerText in Html Agility Pack (table)

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I have a table like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Some Text</th>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>
     ....
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>
    <a href="" title="Students">Names</a>
  </th>
  <td>
      <a href="">Target Text 1</a>
      <a href="">Target Text 2</a>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>
    <a href="" title="Classes">ClassNo</a>
  </th>
  <td>
      <a href="">Some Text</a>
      <a href="">Some Text</a>
  </td>  
</tr>
.....
```

I need to get Target Texts.

"Names" is a header. It is not a variable. 
In this case I have to reach the Node with innerText = Names first.

When I try something like that;

```
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

foreach (HtmlNode table in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
            {                
                foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
                {                    
                    foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td"))
                    {                        
                        if (cell.InnerText.Contains("Names"))
                        {                    
                          MessageBox.Show(cell.NextSibling.InnerText);                                                       
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Output is like single text. (No space between target texts) Because I couldn't find a way to reach to individual links. I could get them only as a single text.

```
Target Text 1Target Text 2
```

Also I believe there is better and proper way to reach these texts. But I couldn't find. It will be great if it is possible to search innerText "Names" (it is `<th>`) and then get `<a>` in `<td>`.

Links can be more than 2. So basically I need to get all of them.

```
<td>
      <a href="">Target Text 1</a>
      <a href="">Target Text 2</a>
      <a href="">Target Text 3</a>
      <a href="">Target Text 4</a>
  </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// @nuget: HtmlAgilityPack

using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Linq;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var html =
       @"<table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <a href='' title='other'>other row</a>
            </th>
            <td>
              <a href=''>Target Text 1</a>
              <a href=''>Target Text 2</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <a href='' title='Students'>Names</a>
            </th>
            <td>
              <a href=''>Target Text 1</a>
              <a href=''>Target Text 2</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <th>
                <a href='' title='Classes'>ClassNo</a>
              </th>
              <td>
                  <a href=''>Some Text</a>
                  <a href=''>Some Text</a>
              </td>  
        </tr>";

            var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
            var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a").Where(x => x.Attributes["title"] != null && x.Attributes["title"].Value == "Students").First();

            Console.WriteLine(node.ParentNode.SelectNodes("//td").First().OuterHtml);

        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works if  "Names" row is first row in the table. But there are some other rows before "Names" row. So "Students -> Names" row is not first row.

Comment: sorry, you're right. edited the answer, changed the node line: var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a").Where(x => x.Attributes["title"] != null && x.Attributes["title"].Value == "Students").First();

Comment: added other row before the "names" test it, it seems work